# Java: client-server socket programming - server returns, but not receiving at client

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

- I've a client-server connection. The client sends out request to server in a predefined format to initiate some processing at server. Server does this processing and then returns the result in predefined format to client.
- Processing at server may take upto 15 mins.
- I'm using reqObject.toString() to convert the request/response to string and then send through network using readUTF and writeUTF (reading the whole buffer).

Now the issue:

- Data send by client is received properly and the processing happens. Once that is done, if the processing takes LESSTHAN 5 mins, once server sends the data, client receives it normally.
- But if processing takes MORETHAN 5-6 mins, server sends back data, but client doesnt receive it (times out after given timeout period).

Code snippet:
Client:

```
Socket server = null;
OutputStream outToServer = null;
DataOutputStream out = null;
InputStream inFromServer = null;
DataInputStream in = null;

if(msg != null){ 
try
{
    server = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
    server.setSoTimeout(1000 * 60 * timeoutInMins); //set to 30 mins
    outToServer = server.getOutputStream();
    out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
    out.writeUTF(msg);
    out.flush();

    // now wait for Server reply
    inFromServer = server.getInputStream();
    in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
    responseString = in.readUTF();
    // do something with response
}
```

Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket client = null;
try{
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
} catch (Exception e) {//log this}
try
{
  while(true)
  {
    client = serverSocket.accept();

    if(client.getRemoteSocketAddress() != null){
        try{
            ReqObject request = getRequest(client);
            // do processing. this may take upto 10-15 mins at max
            sendBackResponse(client, request);
        }

        // do remaining


private void sendBackResponse(Socket client, ReqObject result) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try{
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        String outToClient = result.toString();
        out.writeUTF(outToClient);
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        try{out.close();}catch(IOException e){}
    }
}

private ReqObject getRequest(Socket client) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream in = null;
    in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    String incoming = in.readUTF();
    return convertMessageToRequest(incoming);
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Java, so I cannot solve your problem. But I suggest, you analyze the network status of both computers using TCPView (from Sysinternals Suite) and 'hercules' from HW group.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss : Thnx Tobias. I'll check that. But i believe there shoudn't be any network issue, as the response reaches back at client if the processing at server takes less than 5 mins..

Comment: Yes, but maybe the socket is disconnected after 5 minutes for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you give a shot of this and let us know what happened :        
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);

Comment: So the timeout is too short. So lengthen it. Unclear what you're actually asking. NB `getRemoteSocketAddress()` can't return null at the point you are testing it. The test is pointless.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss : ok, will check that.

Comment: @SaqibRezwan : will let you know.. I was trying with socket.setKeepAlive(true), which didnt solve the issue.

Comment: @EJP : read the question completely, i've mentioned that time out is 30 mins, and processing takes at max 15mins to complete. For more clarity, i've checked at server and verified that response is getting send, within 15mins..

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your suggestions.. :) @TobiasKnauss, I couldn't do the  scanning as network admins prohibited that. Anyway got to know from them the probable cause, which turned out to be the correct one. Thanks for your suggestion.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection was getting disconnected/blocked by a firewall which was in between, after 5 mins of inactivity.

To overcome this, I started sending heartbeat message (with junk data) every 2 minute. This kept the connection alive till the operation completed.

Note: The keepalive() method provided by java didn't help..